# Specific question closed as a duplicate of general question - the consequences

Tags: discussion, questions

I stumbled upon [question A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51578091/343721) which was marked as a duplicate of [question B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). I see several issues with this:

- A is (in my view) well phrased question of occasional user who is kept on low level privileges due to reputation.
- B is just (in my view) too general question asked probably out of curiosity, the author didn't even specified what does he have on mind.

It might be better if A is not closed and B is closed as too broad with links to particular subcategories.

Today, questions like B gets more and more attention and their authors gets more and more reputation for no effort and in vain because they often don't know what to do with it. New authors of questions like A are often enthusiastic and active, but they gets leeched by questions B, their priviledges stay low and they can not participate more.

In my case (17k) I am more or less inactive since cca 5k rep, I have different interests already, I don't use my time to bother with reviews and I don't even know about new features, yet my priviledges grows at the expense of new users and this is just unfair and counterproductive.

### Update

OK, we managed to close the bad question B for obvious reasons:

- *I have witnessed some very strange behaviour...* - **unclear which behaviour**
- *How does this work and when should it be used?* - **too broad**

Now let's reopen the A. I rephrased its title to make the point clearer. How can the user find his answer to his perfectly valid question by redirecting to B? Accepted answer quoting EcmaScript this keyword, setTimeout example, entering eval code... nothing related. Scroll down... okay, the next one answers it in parts 2 + 3, but it is bloated, focusing on the broad question B. Just pointing at the difference between scope and context with a short code snippet would be enough for the question A. Answering to B that way would be incomplete in question B's context, so how the A can get its answer?

### The point

I'd like **not** to close questions as duplicates pointing to vague broad questions with broad answers. I'd like to appreciate low rated users asking sincere well-phrased questions. If a new question is put better than similar older question, I'd like the new question roll over the old question somehow (instead of marking it as a duplicate of the older question).

Comment: So what is it exactly that you suggest? To answer every question about the `this` keyword on it's own? The reason why we have such canonical duplicates is that these questions get ask all the time. Pointing them to a good answer about it seems to be a good idea.

Comment: I suggest to close broad questions and use them as a signpost to more specific questions. There is a difference between duplicates and questions which differs in details. Old questions are often plain bad (in my view), but contains good answers (which were stolen from more specific questions marked as duplicates). That is (in my view) a serious problem which slowly renders SO as a museum of outdated questions. Everybody knows it, some wants to keep it.

Comment: _Old questions are often plain bad (in my view), but contains good answers_ so edit the “bad” question until it’s good, you have the privileges to do so. Then everyone wins

Comment: *(which were stolen from more specific questions marked as duplicates)*: Where did you get that idea from? A lot of this questions/answers have been created to be used as a duplicate target. What's the point of closing a more general question with a great answer as a duplicate of a specific question with a less good answer? Keeping all the information in one place is (imho) the best on the long run.

Comment: Also note, that most of this highly used canonical questions are community wikis, thus noone gets reputation from it. (for the question here, the question isn't but the answer is). Let's assume for a moment we would close B as a duplicate of A: Is it likely that A will get a better answer than B already has? Would it make it easier to find an answer to the topic? I'd say no for both cases.

Comment: Tons of old questions are bad in the meaning of too broad or unclear, it is too late to improve them because they contains many answer addressing every possible aspects. The problem is they are highly cross-linked, highly upvoted due to the avalanche effect, yet often hard to use for the exact problem which particular people are looking for. In this form old questions are similar to books which are very useful to read, but simple and clear answers are vanishing and that is not good.

Comment: @BDL Question A asks for `this` behavior in nested functions (perharps the title should be rephrased), B is just sheer bad, note the *I have witnessed some very strange behaviour with it...* - which behaviour? Unclear, broad - close this sh*t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm bothered by this too, especially the 'museum effect'. But I think the answer to your question is actually covered [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) just under Dr. Strangedupe in the 3 official guidelines put forth.

[image: Dr Strangelove/Strangedupe]

Given that (1) perfection is impossible (2) to many dupes is bad and (3) a **few** similar questions with their own answers are conditions for the end state, then the answer to your question is pretty simple:

Given these rules what should happen is that both stay around and the better worded question A will become one of the few mentioned in (3).

--> In the particular case you mentioned with the links you provided, I think your actual greviance is not with any particular policy, but the fact that question A was overzealously closed before it was given a chance to be one of the few. Probably because whomever marked it as duplicate didn't know/believe/understand the Dr. Strangedupe philosophy, and instead subscribes to the 'Highduper' philosophy that like Highlander: "*There can be only one.*"

[image]

Comment: Hah, answering with pictures (or interpretative dance) has its beauty. Nevertheless, interesting reading. Let me read some more from Jeff's blog first...